# How to initialise rails model based on its association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, constructor, many-to-many, associations

I have been trying to figure out the following, but havent been able to come up with neat solution. Maybe I am missing something basic.

**Overview**

I have a many-to-many task and user model.

One user can have many tasks, and one task may be shared between many  users.

I create tasks using the following:

```
user.tasks.create
```

The task links with the user by the user_id and the user_id links with the task using the task_id, using :through task_table

A task belongs to a user, but once finished, it is passed onto the next user of the task.

**Problem**

It is always the case that for the user that creates the task, it is his turn to finish the task. Once done, it is passed to the next user.

I currently have:

```
  user1.tasks.create(:current_user => user1.id)
```

when the user finishes the task, :current_user changes.

What I am trying to achieve is a way of just having to write user1.tasks.create - and automatically the current_user is set, without explicitly having to pass in user1.id. Is there any way I can do this? Maybe using a constructor (I have pretty much tried all of them, but cant get any to work).

Thanks!

Comment: After what logic do you want to choose the first 'current_user'?

Comment: right after user.tasks.create -> when the task is constructed

Comment: Ah no I mean how do you choose the first user: First in DB, earliest created_at, etc.?

Comment: the first user is the user that creates the task itself ... for example user1 creates the task, then the first user would be user1 ... does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this in a `before_add` callback on your association, something like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, :through => :task_table, :before_add => Proc.new { |u,t| t.current_user = u }
end
```